# How to convert FlatButton to textButton with number validator

Tags: flutter

```
Row(  
children : [  
Expanded(  
 child : AbsorbPointer(  
absorbing: _validPhoneNumber **?** false **:** true,  
child **:** FlatButton(  
color **:** _validPhoneNumber  
**?** Theme.of(context).primaryColor  
**:** Colors.grey,  
child: Text(  
_validPhoneNumber  
**?** 'PROCESSED'  
**:** 'ENTER YOUR PHONE NUMBER',  
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),  
),  
onPressed : () {},  
),  
),  
),  
],  
),
```

trying this code but got some error for color line

```
Row(  
children: [  
Expanded(  
child: AbsorbPointer(  
absorbing: _validPhoneNumber **?** false **:** true,  
child: TextButton(  
**color**  : _validPhoneNumber  
**?** Theme.of(context).primaryColor  
**:** Colors.grey,  
child: Text(  
_validPhoneNumber  
**?** 'PROCESSED'  
**:** 'ENTER YOUR PHONE NUMBER',  
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),  
),  
onPressed: () {},  
),  
),  
),  
],  
)
```

Answer (score 3):

TextButton widget API does not expose a color property. However, you can pass a TextButton.styleFrom factory to the style property as shown below.

```
TextButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.white,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('Click'),
)
```